# Is there an equivalent to the Ruby Shellwords module for the Windows shell?

Tags: ruby, windows, shell, command-line-arguments

I need to construct Windows shell commandlines from arrays in Ruby. If I were using Bash, I could use the standard Shellwords module. Is there an equivalent to Shellwords for the Windows shell, which can safely transform an array to a commandline string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to me there is in fact no Windows analogue to Shellwords unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I've settled on the following:

```
require 'os'
class String
  def ~
    if OS.windows?
      return '"' + self.gsub('"', '""') + '"'
    else
      return self.shellescape
    end
  end
end
```

which allows me to shellescape any string by doing

```
~"some string with cruft&! in it"
```

Comment: should be noted that `os` comes from the os gem, which can be found here: https://github.com/rdp/os - while not a huge problem, it does add a dependency. There is this Question over here that discusses windows detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871309/what-is-the-correct-way-to-detect-if-ruby-is-running-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a version of shellwords with windows support:
https://github.com/larskanis/shellwords

Not upstream yet as far as I see.