# 'system cannot find the path specified' when running `rake test_app` with Spree 1.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I'm on Rails 3.2 and Spree 1.1. When running the initial `rake test_app --trace` I get:

```
** Invoke test_app (first_time)
** Execute test_app
** Invoke common:test_app (first_time)
** Execute common:test_app
Generating dummy Rails application...
Setting up dummy database...
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm running `rake test_app` from `spree\core`. As far as I can tell from `spree\core\lib\generators\spree\dummy\templates\rails\database.yml`, Spree is looking for `db\spree_test.sqlite3`. I tried manually creating this DB but without luck.

Also I'm on Windows 7 if that's helpful as it may be an environment setting of some sort.

Comment: Please show us the steps you used to get to this point. It's very hard for us to debug this issue as we don't know where you're running `rake test_app` at all.

Comment: The same error, making steps from this tutorial: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/creating_extensions.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a small bug in Spree generator:

```
puts "Setting up dummy database..."
cmd = "bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare"

if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/ #windows
  cmd += " >nul"
else
  cmd += " >/dev/null"
end

system(cmd)
```

In my case RUBY_PLATFORM is "i386-mingw32" and else block adds " >/dev/null" which is valid silencer for linux but gives the error in windows.

So easy fix could be:

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw/
```

As I can see from posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784109/detecting-operating-systems-in-ruby) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871309/what-is-the-correct-way-to-detect-if-ruby-is-running-on-windows) there is no reliable way to determine running OS, but there is some heuristic code.

Code is taken from spree\core\lib\spree\testing_support\common_rake.rb

Otherwise you can just run:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:test:prepare
```

Comment: for now (2017-01), to check if the platform is windows you can use `Gem.win_platform?` cf [ruby doc: Method: Gem.win_platform?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubygems/rubygems/Gem.win_platform%3F)