# What's the best-practice way to find out the platform ruby is running on?

Tags: ruby, cross-platform, multiplatform

I am using `colored` gem for coloured printing in the terminal and ruby logger.  I need to run this code on linux and on windows.

On windows, I must first `require 'win32console'` or else coloured printing doesn't work (I just see ANSI escape characters instead).  But if I require win32console on linux it breaks, obviously.

What's the usual way to handle a situation like this in ruby?  I noticed the `RUBY_PLATFORM` variable, but on a windows VM I tried it was `"i386-mingw32"` or something strange.  Using that plus a conditional seems like a pretty flakey way to go about what I need, so I was hoping this problem has a better solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the OS? If so this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on

Comment: Yep, I saw that question.  The answer there is the kind of thing I thought seemed kinda cheap and flakey ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always:

```
begin
  require 'win32console'
rescue LoadError
end
```

I find this easier to write and reason about that trying to decide for myself which OS I'm on and whether or not to load it.

**Update:** I was thinking win32console was built-in rather than a gem.  I believe Win32API is available on all Windows installs, so it's a good proxy to test "Is this Windows?" (rather than "What OS is this, and is that Windows?").

```
begin
  require 'Win32API'
  windowsOS = true
rescue LoadError
  windowsOS = false
end

if windowsOS
  begin
    require 'win32console'
  rescue LoadError
    # Prompt user to install win32console gem
  end
end
```

Comment: I considered this approach, but it would also mean that the windows users would silently fail if they didn't have 'win32console' gem.  So I still need a way to differentiate between those windows users, who should go and install the gem, and the linux users who can safely ignore the LoadError

Comment: @wim Sorry, I was thinking win32console was part of the Ruby install.  I'm fairly certain Win32API in fact is, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a nicer alternative, provided there's not too much overhead in the otherwise unneeded `require 'Win32API'`

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with using RUBY_PLATFORM, it is its purpose.
You could also ask it the OS itself, for windows that would be

```
ENV['OS']
```

Which gives "Windows_NT" on a Vista.

Don't know the counterpart for the other OS.

See also:

- [Detecting Operating Systems in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784109/detecting-operating-systems-in-ruby)
- [How can I find which operating system my Ruby program is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on)