# Detecting Linux distribution/platform in Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, operating-system, platform

I can check the operating system of the platform that is running my Ruby code in a several ways:

- `RUBY_PLATFORM`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/171011/462015
- `RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586108/462015

Is it possible to know what Linux distribution is running? For example a Debian based or a Red Hat based distribution.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/

Answer (score 3):

As pointed above in the comment section, it seems that there is no sure "works in every distribution" way of doing this. What follows is what I've used to detect what kind of an environment a script is being run:

```
def linux_variant
  r = { :distro => nil, :family => nil }

  if File.exists?('/etc/lsb-release')
    File.open('/etc/lsb-release', 'r').read.each_line do |line|
      r = { :distro => $1 } if line =~ /^DISTRIB_ID=(.*)/
    end
  end

  if File.exists?('/etc/debian_version')
    r[:distro] = 'Debian' if r[:distro].nil?
    r[:family] = 'Debian' if r[:variant].nil?
  elsif File.exists?('/etc/redhat-release') or File.exists?('/etc/centos-release')
    r[:family] = 'RedHat' if r[:family].nil?
    r[:distro] = 'CentOS' if File.exists?('/etc/centos-release')
  elsif File.exists?('/etc/SuSE-release')
    r[:distro] = 'SLES' if r[:distro].nil?
  end

  return r
end
```

This is not a complete solution to handle every GNU/Linux distribution on earth. Far from it, actually. For example it makes no distinction between OpenSUSE and SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, though they are two quite different beasts. Besides, it's quite a spaghetti even with just a few distros. But it might be something one might be able to build on.

You can find a more complete example of distribution detection from the [source code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter) of [Facter](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/facter-part-1-facter-101) which is used, among other things, to feed facts to a configuration management system [Puppet](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet).

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this looks horrible and doesn't work in all environment like Amazon instances that you need to see in `/etc/system-release`. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Linux distribution is a collection of software, usually distinguishable by their package manager, window system, window manager, and desktop environment. That's a lot of interchangeable parts. If a system keeps the package manager, but changes the window system and desktop environment, do we call it a new distribution? There's no definitive answer, so various tools will give slightly different answers.

**[Train](https://github.com/inspec/train)** has a [whole hierarchy](https://github.com/inspec/train/blob/51f91f89f6f80e6f4b737605871eb6faef7f25f8/lib/train/platforms/detect/specifications/os.rb) of distribution families and may be the most sophisticated of the bunch. A quick comparison of Train and Ohai [is here](https://github.com/inspec/train/issues/331#issuecomment-414086833). It's designed to be run over a network connection, but works fine locally, too, as shown here:

```
# gem install train
Train.create('local').connection.os[:name] #=> eg. "centos", "linuxmint"
Train.create('local').connection.os[:family] #=> eg. "redhat", "debian"
```

**[Facter](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/)**'s [osfamily fact](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.11/core_facts.html#osfamily) returns, eg. "Debian" for Ubuntu. With Facter, the general form for retrieving facts is `Facter[factname].value`.

```
# gem install facter
require 'facter'
puts Facter['osfamily'].value
```

**[Ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)**'s `platform_family` fact returns, eg. ["debian" for Ubuntu](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/dbbd71fd79de6f03492e69936467412c43463a4e/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb#L142..L288) and "rhel" for CentOS. With Ohai, the general form for retrieving facts is `node[factname]`.

```
# gem install ohai
node['platform'] #=> eg. "ubuntu" or "mint"
node['platform_family'] #=> eg. "debian" for Ubuntu and Mint
```

#### Ruby system info libraries which won't distinguish platforms

**[Platform](https://github.com/kraigstrong/platform)** retrieves some basic data, and can distinguish well between a variety of Unix platforms. However, it doesn't handle different distributions of Linux at all. `Platform::IMPL` will return :freebsd, :netbsd, :hpux, etc., but all Linux distros are just :linux. **[sys-uname](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-uname)** and **[sysinfo](https://github.com/delano/sysinfo/blob/master/lib/sysinfo.rb#L16)** are similar. **[utilinfo](https://github.com/ArunSahadeo/utilinfo)** is even more basic, and will fail on any systems beyond Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not indicate the purpose. If the purpose is to determine if a distribution-specific command is available, this might be an appropriate answer.

The Ruby standard library provides [find_executable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html#method-i-find_executable). You can use `find_executable` and `find_executable0` to check the package manager.

For example, to detect Debian, or derivatives such as Ubuntu, just check for the existence of `dpkg`.

```rb
require 'mkmf'

MakeMakefile::Logging.instance_variable_set(:@logfile, nil)
puts "Debian compatible" if find_executable0 'dpkg'
```

To detect Ubuntu, or a derivative such as Mint, check for `apt`.

```rb
require 'mkmf'

MakeMakefile::Logging.instance_variable_set(:@logfile, nil)
puts "Ubuntu compatible" if find_executable0 'apt'
```

Note that `find_executable` outputs a message, which you might not want. `find_executable0` performs the same task, without generating the message:

```rb
irb(main):006> require 'mkmf'
=> false
irb(main):007> find_executable 'dpkg'
checking for dpkg... yes
=> "/usr/bin/dpkg"
irb(main):008> find_executable0 'dpkg'
=> "/usr/bin/dpkg"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'facter'

puts Facter['osfamily'].value
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22408692)