# Bundling taglib with taglib-ruby

Tags: ruby, compilation, makefile, rubygems, taglib

I'm writing an application that uses [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby), which in turn depends on [Taglib](http://taglib.github.io). So that the user doesn't have to download and install taglib themselves, I want to bundle it with my application. I don't have much experience doing this kind of thing, but my sense is that I need to do the following:

1. Compile Taglib to a folder within my app
2. Compile taglib-ruby, pointing it to the local Taglib from the previous step

The problem I'm running into is that `rake clean compile` in step 2 fails with the error:

> checking for main() in -ltag... no
>
> You must have taglib installed in order to use taglib-ruby.

If I simply `brew install taglib`, then step 2 runs without a problem. I have tried step 1 in two ways: 1) simply copying the installed files from Homebrew's `Cellar` directory after running `brew install`, and 2) Downloading and running `cmake` on the extracted contents of one of the tar files on [Taglib's website](http://taglib.github.io/).

Since this error obviously suggests that `rake clean compile` can't find my non-Homebrew installed version of Taglib, I tried editing the `opt_dirs` variable in the [extconf_common.rb](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby/blob/master/ext/extconf_common.rb) file in taglib-ruby, but no luck.

How can I get taglib-ruby to use a locally installed version of Taglib?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off not to bundle the dependency unless it is necessary to.

There's a few reasons:

1. The dependency needs to be build differently for different platforms. It's easier to direct users to `apt-get/brew install taglib` than to include the latest build for all system architectures and then try and determine which one to install.
2. The dependency might not get updated unless it's installed via a package manager.

Perhaps you could make an install script which determines the user's platform and then downloads the dependency using the appropriate package manager.

See [Detecting Operating Systems in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784109/detecting-operating-systems-in-ruby)