# How do I get the specific OS version on Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am well aware that you can check your current OS using the `os` gem. But what I have not found is how to get the specific OS version. For example, if I am running the Ruby project on Windows 8.1, I want Windows 8.1 to be printed instead of just Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586108/954421

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand my question. The links you provided don't provide the version number

Answer (score 0):

I've take a look on the specs of OS gem and unfortunately I couldn't find such method or attribute for that.

One alternative: you can execute your own system calls (via cocaine gem):

1. on linux you can find through `lsb-release` or other methods
2. on OSX: `sw_vers -productVersion`
3. On Windows `ver` through command.

*Perhaps you can try to add it on the gem itself create a new PR?*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the gem sys-uname : https://rubygems.org/gems/sys-uname

```
require 'sys/uname'
include Sys

class Test
  puts Uname.uname
end
```

This is the output:

....., build_number="7601", build_type="Multiprocessor Free", caption="Microsoft Windows 7 Professional ", code_set="1252", country_code="1", creation_class_name="Win32_OperatingSystem", cscreation_class_name="Win32_ComputerSystem", csd_version="Service Pack 1", ...

plus other details

Comment: Uname.sysname gives you the OS name